# Set Keyboard type in WKWebView -- iOS Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4

How can i set a keyboard with globe icon (language change option) in WKWebView, so that in the webview when a input field is selected, the keyboard with globe always appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can configure some keyboard attributes for text input elements.
>   For example, you can include autocorrect and autocapitalize attributes
>   in the definition of an input element to specify the keyboard’s
>   behaviors, as shown in the following example.

```
<input type="text" size="30" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="on">
```

> You can also control which type of keyboard is displayed when a user
>   touches a text field in a web page. To display a telephone keypad, an
>   email keyboard, or a URL keyboard, use the tel, email, or url keywords
>   for the type attribute on an input element, respectively. To display a
>   numeric keyboard, set the value of the pattern attribute to "[0-9]*"
>   or "\d*".
>
> These keywords and the pattern attribute are part of HTML 5 and are
>   available in iOS. The following list shows how to display each type of
>   keyboard, including the standard keyboard.

```
Text: <input type="text"></input>
Telephone: <input type="tel"></input>
URL: <input type="url"></input>
Email: <input type="email"></input>
Zip code: <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*"></input>
```

for more reference : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW12

Comment: Is it possibe to change the keyboard type from native app forcefuly . For eg when a field in webview is selected force numeric keypad from native app.?